# How take input values to GET API response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i´m new in React and i working with an API of Game Of Thrones. 
I tried and tried but i dont know how is the correct method to take input values and passing to the API to GET the response.

```
class DataComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            loading: false,
            character: {}
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({loading: true})
        fetch(`https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/${name}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                    character: data,
                                    })
            })

    }

    render() {


        return (
            <form>
            <input 
                style={inputStyle}
                name="name"
                value={this.state.name}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                placeholder="First Name"
               />
               <br />
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

I expect take input values and passing to the API and GET the response of the character

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're mixing some concepts.
In the [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), you would call the API if you already know what value to pass. It is invoked immediately after a component is mounted (inserted into the tree). So in your case (at lest in the described context) you don't need that.

You need to do 2 things:
- remove your `componentDidMount` method
- implement the `this.handleChange` to receive the name parameter that is entered and call the API. An example can be:

```
handleChange(event) {
  const name = event.target.value;
  fetch(`https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/${name}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        character: data,
        name: name
      })
    })
}
```

You might have to add `name` in your constructor `this.state=...` code.
Note: the above code is untested but should give you a good idea to implement.